# sum over a specific array index only

Tags: fortran

I am trying to use the SUM intrinsic to sum over only one index in an array, I do not want to sum over all of the elements.  Below I provide a sample code that works fine.

I was wondering if there is an easier way to do this though. If so, how can I optimize this code?  Thanks

```
PROGRAM mysample

INTEGER :: i,j
INTEGER, PARAMETER :: nx = 2, ny = 2
REAL, DIMENSION(nx, ny)  :: f
REAL, DIMENSION(nx)  :: a

DO i = 1,nx
DO j = 1,ny
    f(i,j) = i + 2.*j  
END DO
END DO

DO j = 1,ny 
    a(j) = SUM(f(:,j)) !this line sums over the second array index only
END DO

DO i = 1,nx
    PRINT*, a(i) !the output is correct 
END DO

END PROGRAM
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the optional `Dim` argument to `Sum`

```
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ cat sum.f90 
Program mysample

  Implicit None

  Integer :: i,j
  Integer, Parameter :: nx = 2, ny = 2
  Real, Dimension(nx, ny)  :: f
  Real, Dimension(nx)  :: a, b

  Do i = 1,nx
     Do j = 1,ny
        f(i,j) = i + 2.*j  
     End Do
  End Do

  Do j = 1,ny 
     a(j) = Sum(f(:,j)) 
  End Do

  Do i = 1,nx
     Write( *, * ) 'Reference: ' , a(i) !the output is correct 
  End Do

  b = Sum( f, Dim = 1 )

  Write( *, * ) 'Intrinsic: ', b

End Program mysample
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ gfortran -std=f2008 -Wall -Wextra -fcheck=all -O -g sum.f90 
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ ./a.out
 Reference:    7.00000000    
 Reference:    11.0000000    
 Intrinsic:    7.00000000       11.0000000
```

Comment: This is really helpful.  I have one question, how does Dim = 1 refer to the 2nd array index?  For ex: why doesn't it refer to the 1st array index instead?  If I wanted to sum the first array index only, would I use Dim = 0?  Thanks so much for your clear answer, you don't even use DO loops at all, it seems much cleaner than mine.  And, what if I had an array of 3 indices, and I wanted to sum the last two indices, how could I use DIM in that sense?  Those are all of my questions.  Thank you.

Comment: As written the sum in your code is over the first index - hence Dim = 1.

Comment: Okay, I actually meant to sum over the second index.  I didn't realize that.  Thanks for pointing out my error.  What if I had an array of 3 indices, and I wanted to sum the last two indices, how could I use DIM in that sense?

Comment: No. Dim must be a scalar. Though something like Sum( Sum( a, Dim = 3 ), Dim = 2 ) might work - but it's too late for me to work it out in my head.

Comment: No problem, that comment is very helpful.  I can figure out how to use DIM now by explicitly just writing out the sums.  Thanks a lot for your answer!

Comment: You're certainly right.  Using SUM(SUM(f, DIM =3), DIM =2) gives me exactly what I need.  Thanks.